# Event to update listing every minute

Tags: mysql, sql, database, events, select

I am trying to automatically update my `listings` table's buyer_ID column with the highest `bidder_ID` from the `bids` table. My issue is that... how can I get the `bid_listing` that correlates to the `listing_ID` from the `listing` table?

My current event query:

```
CREATE EVENT updateAuction
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
    SET buyer_ID = (SELECT MAX(bidder_ID) FROM bids WHERE bid_listing = (Need each listing_ID from the listings table here)) 
    FROM listings
    WHERE list_expires < now()
    AND buyer_ID = NULL
```

**Schema for bids**

```
bid_ID bid_listing bidder_ID bid_amount
```

**Schema for listings**

```
listing_ID list_expires buyer_ID sold_price
```

Comment: Using `SET buyer_ID` how does the DB know which table you mean? You need an `update` statement

Comment: @juergend oops.. will fix that part

Comment: And actually - do you really need that? Why not calculate the data on demand in a SELECT?

Comment: @juergend how can I do that?

Comment: Your BIDS table does not contain a bid_amount column or smething like that

Comment: @juergend it does.. updated it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on code example and your statement of "the highest bidder_ID from the bids table"

I think what you need is an **UPDATE JOIN**

```
Update listings set
   buyer_id = table2.max_bidder
From listings table1
Inner Join ( Select bids.listing_ID
                  , max(bids.bidder_ID) as max_bidder 
             From bids
             Group by listing_ID ) table2
        on ( table1.listing_ID = table2.listing_ID )
WHERE list_expires < now()
    AND buyer_ID is NULL
```

Here is another example of the **UPDATE JOIN** using SUB QUERIES to get the bidder_id with the highest bid amount.

```
UPDATE listings set
    buyer_id   = table2.bidder_ID 
  , sold_price = table2.bid_amount  /* Optional */
From listings table1
Inner Join ( Select bids.listing_ID, bids.bidder_ID, bids.bid_amount
             From bids
             Inner Join ( Select bids.listing_ID 
                               , max(bid_amount) as bid_amount
                          From bids
                          Inner Join listings 
                                  on ( bids.listing_ID = bids.listing_ID )
                          Where list_expires < now()
                            and buyer_ID is NULL 
                        ) winning_amount
                    on (     bids.listing_ID = winning_amount.listing_ID 
                         and bids.bid_amount = winning_amount.bid_amount
                       )
           ) table2
        on ( table1.listing_ID = table2.listing_ID )
WHERE list_expires < now()
    AND buyer_ID is NULL
```

I hope it helps

Regards

Comment: it's giving a syntax error `From listings table1 Inner Join ( Select bids.listing_ID , m' at line 3`

Comment: I don't think `From listings table1` is needed